# How can numbers that have more than 2 prime factors (ie. 12) be the product of primes? Isn’t 12 the product of one prime and one composite?

Tags: prime-factorization

Wikipedia “In number theory, the fundamental theorem of arithmetic ...the unique-prime-factorization theorem, states that every integer greater than 1 either is prime itself **or is the product of prime numbers”.**..The theorem is stating...first, that (a composite number) **can be represented as a product of primes**...

Example A: 6 = 2 x 3 
I take it that “is the product of” means that if we carry out the calculation and multiply these **prime**factors **only** (2 x 3) we will get the answer 6. This makes sense.

Example B: 12 = 2 x 2 x 3 
**I am assuming that in math we can only calculate one set of numbers at a time**. So we can either do 2 x 2= 4 then 4 x 3 =12.
or 2 x 3= 6 then 2 x 6 =12

4 and 6 are not prime numbers so how can we say that the composite number 12 is the product of prime numbers? Isn’t it the product of one prime number and one composite number?  12= (4 x 3) or (2 x 6).

So any non prime  number that has more than 2 prime factors cannot be the product of primes because by multiplying 3 or more prime numbers you will get a composite number before you get to the answer.  Example. 20= 2 x 2 x 5
20= 4 x 5 or 20 = 2 x 10 
 To solve this problem you will either get a 4 or a 10 before you can multiply it by the last prime number in the equation.

Comment: We certainly allow products with more than two factors.

Comment: Just because $12=(3)(4)$ is a product of a prime and a composite doesn't prevent it from also being a product of the three primes $2,2,3$, since $12=(2)(2)(3)$. All the theorem says is that an integer greater than one is either prime, or can be obtained as the result of multiplying two or more primes (not necessarily distinct), and that the prime factors are unique, apart from the order of the factors.

Comment: I would add that it makes sense to define product of more than two factors, since the product checks the property of associativity: $(2\times2)\times 3=2\times(2\times 3)$, so there is no problem writing $12=2\times2\times3$.

Comment: The theorem states that every non prime number can be created using product of primes, and that the primes we use are unique, i.e. exactly one combination of primes will get you to a number. The way you calculate the product is irrelevant, yes $2\times 2\times 3=2\times 6$ but it is irrelevant

Comment: In other words: every non-prime natural number $a$ has a unique situation to the equation $\prod_{i=0}^n p_i^\ell=a$ where $\ell$ is a natural number and $p_i$ is a prime. It state nothing about the other factors

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly reasonable question; the OP has clearly thought about it and just didn't understand the terminology.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia article assumes that "a product of ... numbers" means that you have two **or more** numbers and that you will multiply them **all** together. For example, in **that** sense, $12=2\times2\times 3$ is a product of prime numbers.

If they wanted to say what you think they said, they would say something like "every number ... or is a product of exactly two prime numbers". They would then be wrong, as you have already noticed.

Comment: In fact, I would even go further than WP and view a single prime as product of one prime factor and $1$ as product of zero prime factors ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen from the op' question, Wikipedia says: "... every integer greater than 1 either is prime itself or is the product of prime numbers"